# SQL, company has more abbo, just select only the dubble ones

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  ( SELECT 
                        KltBedrijfsNaam 
                    FROM
                        [tbl relaties] 
                    WHERE
                        KltId = auoKltId
                ) AS Naam,
                auoNaam

                    FROM
                        dbo.tblAutomatischeOrdere
                        WHERE  
                auoStatus = 'LO'
```

a Naam has more auoNaam, but there are 2 of the same auoNaam for a Naam. and i want only to show those two. i want to have Naam and de 2 auoNaam
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOOP0.png)

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: Pls provide table structure, sample data and expected output.

Comment: i want a query that shows me a Naam thats shows me 2 of the  same auoNaam on him

Comment: All you're doing here is get the KltBedrijfsNaam from the mother table as an extra field (apparently you have denormalized and store the client name in Orders too??). So the amount of records is determined by tblAUtomatischeOrdere and nothing else.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you mean is:

```
Select KltBedrijfsnaam, auoNaam from tblRelaties, tblAutomatischeOrdere
WHERE KltId = auoKltId AND auoStatus = 'LO'
```

But yeah, you should try to provide more info and what you want exactly.